# Surprisingly simple approximation for particular parameter of definite integral over trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

In physical problem, I have three following integrals:
$$
    \Phi_0(r)  =  4\pi r \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} \left( \frac{\sin(r t)}{t(\pi^2-r^2 t^2)}\right)^2 \mathrm{d} t 
$$
$$
    \Phi_1(r)  =  4\pi r \int_0^{\infty} \cos(t) \left( \frac{\sin(r t)}{t(\pi^2-r^2 t^2)}\right)^2 \mathrm{d} t
$$
$$
    \Phi_2(r) = 4\pi r \int_0^{\infty} t \sin(t) \left( \frac{\sin(r t)}{t(\pi^2-r^2 t^2)}\right)^2 \mathrm{d} t 
$$

I was not able to solve these integrals in elementary functions. However, numerically, I am pretty confident that for the particular set of parameters $r\in (0,0.5)$  they are reduced with precision at least $10^{-10}$ to elementary functions $\Phi_0(r)\simeq 0.202642367284674 r^3$ (correct to $\sim 10^{-14}$), $\Phi_1(r)\simeq\Phi_2(r)\simeq0$.

For $r>0.5$, these integrals are much less trivial and I do not know elementary form.

Probably, these integrals are known. Or maybe anyone knows some hints how to show this numerical result analytically?

Comment: Using complex integration,$$\Phi_0(r)=4\pi r \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} \left( \frac{\sin(r t)}{t(\pi^2-r^2 t^2)}\right)^2 dt\overset{t=\frac x{2r}}{=}64\pi r^3\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin\frac x{2r}(1-\cos x)}{x^3\big((2\pi)^2-x^2\big)^2}dx$$
$$=64\pi r^3\cdot\frac1{32\pi^4}=\frac2{\pi^2}r^3\,\,\Big(\frac2{\pi^2}=0.20264236728...\Big); \,r\in[0;\infty)$$

Comment: It is important that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin\frac x{2r}(1-\cos x)}{x^3\big((2\pi)^2-x^2\big)^2}dx\,$ does not depend on $r$. It means that
$$\frac{\Phi_1(r)}{r^3}=\frac{d}{d\big(\frac1r\big)}\,\frac{\Phi_0(r)}{r^3}=0$$
$$\frac{\Phi_2(r)}{r^3}=-\,\frac{d^2}{d\big(\frac1r\big)^2}\,\frac{\Phi_0(r)}{r^3}=0$$

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo: $64\pi r^3\cdot\frac1{32\pi^\color{red}{3}}=\frac2{\pi^2}r^3$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you. It seems, I was confused by my mistake in numerical computations for $r>0.5$ and stopped looking for an answer too early.

Comment: If you need some detailed hints about possible way of evaluation, please let know

Comment: @Svyatoslav In fact, I do not understand how exactly $1/32\pi^3$ is obtained. Could you give some more hints here? I do not see obvious problems in numerical evaluation and it does not give this result for large $r$.

Comment: I'm afraid you are right: the result is correct for $r\in[0;\frac12]$. I will post my solution to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denoting $\displaystyle\alpha=\frac1{2r}$,  the answer is the following:
$$\Phi_0(r)  =  4\pi r \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} \left( \frac{\sin(r t)}{t(\pi^2-r^2 t^2)}\right)^2 \mathrm{d} t$$
$$=\frac{r^3}{\pi^2}\left(2\alpha(2-\alpha)+\frac{1-\alpha}\pi\sin(2\pi\alpha)+\frac2{\pi^2}\big(1-\cos(2\pi\alpha)\big)\right), \alpha\in[0;1]\,\,\big(r\geqslant 1/2\big)\tag{a}$$
$$=\frac{2r^3}{\pi^2};\,\,\alpha\geqslant1\,\big(r\in[0;1/2]\big)\tag{b}$$
Making the substitution $t=\frac xr$
$$\Phi_0(r)=4\pi r^3\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\frac xr}x\left(\frac{\sin x}{x(\pi^2-x^2)}\right)^2dx\tag{1}$$
$$\Phi_1(r)=4\pi r^2\int_0^\infty\cos\frac xr\left(\frac{\sin x}{x(\pi^2-x^2)}\right)^2dx=r^2\frac d{d\big(\frac1r\big)}\frac{\Phi_0(r)}{r^3}$$
$$\Phi_2(r)=4\pi r\int_0^\infty x\sin\frac xr\left(\frac{\sin x}{x(\pi^2-x^2)}\right)^2dx=-r\,\frac d{d\big(\frac1r\big)}\frac{\Phi_1(r)}{r^2}$$
The evaluation is straightforward. Using (1) and $\sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}2$, we can present $\Phi_0(r)$ in the form
$$\Phi_0(r)=128\pi r^3\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin\frac x{2r}(1-\cos x)}{x^3\big((2\pi)^2-x^2)^2}dx$$
Using for convenience the notation $\displaystyle \alpha=\frac1{2r}$
$$\Phi_0(r)=64\pi r^3\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin\alpha x-\frac12\sin x(1+\alpha)-\frac12\sin x(\alpha-1)}{x^3\big((2\pi)^2-x^2\big)^2}dx$$
$$=64\pi r^3\Im\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{i\alpha x}-\frac12e^{ix(1+\alpha)}-\frac12e^{ix(\alpha-1)}}{x^3\big((2\pi)^2-x^2\big)^2}dx$$
Now we go in the complex plane and create the closed contour $C$, adding a big half-circle (counter-clockwise) in the upper half-plane, and three small half-circles (around the points $-2\pi; 0; 2\pi$, clockwise). There are no poles inside the contour; the integral along a big arch $\to0$. Therefore, at $\alpha>1$ (or at $r\in[0;1/2]$)
$$J(\alpha)=\oint_C\frac{e^{i\alpha z}-\frac12e^{iz(1+\alpha)}-\frac12e^{iz(\alpha-1)}}{z^3\big((2\pi)^2-z^2\big)^2}dz=\pi\,i \underset{\binom{z=\pm2\pi}{z=0}}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{e^{i\alpha z}-\frac12e^{iz(1+\alpha)}-\frac12e^{iz(\alpha-1)}}{z^3\big((2\pi)^2-z^2\big)^2}$$
$$\Phi_0(r)=64\pi r^3\Im J(\alpha)=64\pi^2r^3\Re\underset{\binom{z=\pm2\pi}{z=0}}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{e^{i\alpha z}-\frac12e^{iz(1+\alpha)}-\frac12e^{iz(\alpha-1)}}{z^3\big((2\pi)^2-z^2\big)^2}$$
At $\alpha<1$ we present $\Phi_0(r)$ in the form
$$\Phi_0(r)=64\pi r^3\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin\alpha x-\frac12\sin x(1+\alpha)+\frac12\sin x(1-\alpha)}{x^3\big((2\pi)^2-x^2\big)^2}dx$$
$$\Phi_0(r)=64\pi^2r^3\Re\underset{\binom{z=\pm2\pi}{z=0}}{\operatorname{Res}}\frac{e^{i\alpha z}-\frac12e^{iz(1+\alpha)}+\frac12e^{iz(1-\alpha)}}{z^3\big((2\pi)^2-z^2\big)^2}$$
The residues evaluation in both cases is straightforward and gives the answer presented above.

We expect that $\Phi_0(r)$ is a continuous function. Indeed, at  $\alpha =1\,\,(a)=(b)$ (above), and at $\alpha\to 0 \,\,\Phi_0=0$.

Quick numeric check (I did it at $\alpha=\frac14\,\,(r=2)$ ) confirms the result. The answer also reproduces the asymptotics obtained by @Sal in his post.

Comment: Thank you. I checked against numerical integration and your result confirms up to numerical precision for the large range of parameters. The derivation is quite tricky to come up with, but easy to follow.

Comment: The explicite forms of $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ are straightforward, but if you need some help to get them - please, let know. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Phi_0(r)=4\pi r^3 I(r)$, then with the substitution $u=rt$ we have

$$
I(r)=\int\limits_0^\infty du\ \frac{\sin(u/r)}{u} \left(\frac{\sin(u)}{u(\pi^2-u^2)}\right)^2
$$

The other integrals are related to $I$ by differentiation:

$$
\Phi_1=-4\pi r^3I'\\
\Phi_2=-4\pi r^3(r^2I')'
$$

We can find the behavior of $I$ for large or small $r$. When $r$ is large we note the integrand is peaked at $u=0$ to expand $\sin(u/r)\sim \frac{u}{r}-\frac{u^3}{6r^3}$ so that

$$
I(r)\sim \frac{3}{4\pi^3 r} -\frac{1}{24\pi r^3} \qquad,\qquad r\to\infty
$$

For small $r$, we integrate by parts

$$
I(r)=\operatorname{Si}(u/r)\left(\frac{\sin(u)}{u(\pi^2-u^2)}\right)^2\bigg|_0^\infty - \int\limits_0^\infty du \ \operatorname{Si}(u/r) \frac{d}{du}\left(\frac{\sin(u)}{u(\pi^2-u^2)}\right)^2
$$

Where $\operatorname{Si}$ is the [sine integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html). The second term on the RHS is negligible compared to $I$ as $r\to0$ so we have only the boundary term

$$
I(r)\sim\frac{1}{2 \pi^3} \qquad,\qquad r\to 0
$$

Comment: I checked your asymptotic from my solution (+1)

Comment: @Svyatoslav thanks, although they're now obsolete because you got the exact solution :P

Comment: I'm sure that a correct asymptotic is one of the key steps. In case an exact solution can be found, this is a sound way to make sure the solution is correct. Thank you :)